# Foreach con get!

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Función donde buscamos por fechas y con el filtro 2: entregando 2 o 4 un array:

```
$Tabla= Tabla::whereDate('fecha_creada', '>=', $startDate)
->whereDate('fecha_creada', '<=', $endDate)->where('filtro','=',2)->get();
```

Funcion foreach de get

```
foreach($manifold as $mani){
  $materiales = Orden_manifold::where('manifold_id',$mani->id)->where('type',0)->get();
```

La función principal está bien, pero cuando entra al *foreach* solo me entrega el primer dato en vez de recorrer los que encuentra.

Comment: que te responde al agregar `dd($manifold);` alli deverias poder ver que tiene la variable, si es un objeo array o un string

Comment: Muestra la línea donde creas la variable `$manifold`.